# Can't delete a pointer in C++

Tags: pointers, visual-c++

I got this code from a book. When I ran on Visual Studio, it said to switch strcpy() to strcpy_s(), and after I did that, it seems the program terminated at the delete pointer. I tried to run on Dev-C++, and it works fine. Anyone knows why? Thank you.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a kind of animal: ";
    cin >> animal; // ok if input < 20 chars

    ps = animal; // set ps to point to string
    cout << ps << "!\n"; // ok, same as using animal
    cout << "Before using strcpy():\n";
    cout << animal << " at " << (int *)animal << endl;
    cout << ps << " at " << (int *)ps << endl;

    ps = new char[strlen(animal) + 1]; // get new storage
    strcpy_s(ps, sizeof(animal), animal); // copy string to new storage

    cout << "After using strcpy():\n";
    cout << animal << " at " << (int *)animal << endl;
    cout << ps << " at " << (int *)ps << endl;
    delete[] ps;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "terminate"? Could you give more details?

Comment: You may try checking the value of `ret_err` after amending with `errno_t ret_err = strcpy_s(...`, probably 0.

Comment: Hint: `sizeof(animal) != strlen(animal)`